# Objective C using UItextview/NSstring place holders in long strings

Tags: ios, objective-c, string-formatting

please tell me why I get an: Interface type can not be Statically allocated,

error on the code below and what I can do to be able to use this placeholder in the Json string I am building below. Email is a UITextfield.

```
    NSString *CCEmail = email.text;

NSString *jsonInputString =
@"{\"email\": \" %@ \",\"password\": \"iamlearningtocode\"}",CCEmail;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the %@ in your string replaced with the text in CCEmail you need to call

```
NSString *jsonInputString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"email\": \" %@ \",\"password\": \"iamlearningtocode\"}", CCEmail];
```

However with this approach a CCEmail containing `"` would cause the string to become invalid JSON. I suggest you build your data in a proper `NSDictionary` and use `NSJSONSerialization` to convert to string.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `stringWithFormat` method of `NSString` class.
`NSString *jsonInputString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"email\": \" %@ \",\"password\": \"iamlearningtocode\"}",CCEmail];`